# Laravel: Get Event name when using a wildcard event listener

Tags: php, laravel-4

Is there a way to get the name of an event that is firing when you're using a wild card listener?

I'm using the following listener:

```
Event::listen('sentinel.user.login', function (){
    $userLog = new UserLog;
    $logData = array('eventDescription' => "User login.");
    $userLog->submitLog($logData);
});
```

I would like to alter it to catch any event fired from the sentinel user name with a wild card like so:

```
'sentinel.user.*'
```

And then use the particular event that fired as the value for `eventDescription`:

```
$logData = array ('eventDescription' => $eventName);
```

I read through the documentation and API and couldn't find how I would go about doing this, but it seems like there has to be some way to.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `Event::firing()`, which will get the name of the last event that has been fired. Usually this will do what you want but might be complicated if you have nested events.

Comment: Ah, perfect! I must have looked up and down the docs a dozen times and totally overlooked that description. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5, the best way to do this would be to user Event Subscribers :
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events#event-subscribers